# How-to add some content into the balise HEAD with jquery?

Tags: jquery, dojo, addition, head

I'd like to insert dynamiccaly some balises of HTML in the head of the web document. I've tried to add :

```
$("head").append("<style type=\"text/css\"> @import \"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css\";.container { text-align: center; margin: 10px; } .info { margin: 10px; }</style>");
```

But it looks like it doesn't work...

Do you know if it's possible to add dynamiccaly some content in the head balise?

Thank you very much,

Bat

Comment: its possible with javascript http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ ,

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be that you are missing the `url()` bit around your import url.  You also do not need the quotes around the url.  See this reference: http://htmlhelp.com/reference/css/style-html.html#importing

Try changing it to:

```
$("head").append('<style type="text/css"> @import url(http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css); .container { text-align: center; margin: 10px; } .info { margin: 10px; }</style>');
```